# I am On my side, they are at theirs

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Does it make sense to say:
I don't get along with neighbors, I am on my side, they are at theirs"

Meaning we don't have problems/interacting,  we both stay on our own side.

Is there a more suitable idiom ?

Thanks

Comment: You just said: I am **on my side**.  And they are on theirs.

Comment: To be **at someone's side** means something completely different from **on someone's side**.

Answer (score 2):

It's okay.  You have two independent clauses, so either use a full stop (and make two sentences) or use a conjunction like "but" to join the sentences.  You probably mean "*my* neighbours" (rather than any neighbours in general) and there is no reason to change from "*on* my side" to "*at* theirs".  Use "on" for both phrases.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this sentence.

One: You appear to contradict yourself. You say you DON'T get along with the neighbors. But then you say that you each stay on your own side, which would seem to be a way to avoid problems. Do you mean that you don't get along even though you each stay on your own side? Or do you mean that you DO get along because you each stay on your own side.

Two: The word "side" here is ambiguous. I take it that you mean "your own side of the property boundary". But "side" can also mean a participant in a dispute. Like, "There were two sides in World War 2: The Axis and the Allies."

Three: You appear to be trying to set up a parallelism: I am on my side and they are on theirs. But then you use different words, "on" for your side and "at" for theirs, and break the parallelism. You should say, "I am on my side and they are ON theirs." Or in context you would probably be better to say,  "I STAY on my side and they STAY on theirs."

Four: You string together several independent clauses with commas. Even native speakers do this a lot so I wouldn't beat you up for it, but it's incorrect. It's called a "comma splice". You should either: (a) Make them separate sentences, with periods. "I get along with my neighbors. I stay on my side. They stay on theirs." (b) Insert conjuctions. "I get along with my neighbors BECAUSE I stay on my side AND they stay on theirs." (c) Use colons and semicolons: "I get along with my neighbors: I stay on my side; they stay on theirs." (d) Some combination of the above, like, "I get along with my neighbors. I stay on my side; they stay on theirs."

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense, but it's not natural. Here are some ways to express this idea:

> They do their thing, and I do mine.
> We both do our own thing.
> We keep to ourselves.
> We stay out of each others business.
> We leave each other alone.